# How do I change my root document root in XAMPP on windows?

Tags: apache, xampp

I have installed XAMPP in C drive on my windows and i want to change my document root.

Answer (score 0):

Find the `httpd.conf` file which should be located in `Program Files/XAMPP/Apache` or something similar. Open that with a text editor and then find the line which specifies `DocumentRoot`.

Change the path specified to wherever you want your new document root to be and save.

Restart the Apache server and you'll be good to go.

Comment: i did it but its not working.
i even restarted the xampp .

Comment: How is it not working, does it still point to the original root?

Comment: Yes its still referring to the original root

Comment: Ensure that all the slashes in the path are forward slashes and there is not a trailing slash. Also check ~line 203 to ensure that if there's a path specified there that it is also set to your desired path and not the original document root. Save, restart apache and see if that works.